# how to initialize byte array in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8, arrays

I have a byte array like this: (this is not the actual byte array, I have modified it)

```
[69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, 196, 195, 61, 101, 98]
```

I want to know how can I initialize this in Java so that I can convert this byte array to String? Below line doesn't work.

```
// this doesn't work
byte[] bytes = [69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, 196, 195, 61, 101, 98];

// now convert to string
String data = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a byte array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208479/how-do-i-initialize-a-byte-array-in-java)

Comment: nobody expected signed bytes:)  instead of 255, you need to write -1, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work

```
  byte[] bytes = {69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, (byte) 196, (byte) 195, 61, 101, 98};
```

`Byte` can hold upto -128 to 127 only. Some of the values are exceeding the limit of a byte value. So you need to cast them to byte.

Comment: This is probably not what the OP wants. It seems that the intention is to create a string based on the unicode values of different characters.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes. In OP code, the string conversion works, where he failed to initialize the byte array :)