# How to send byte array to BLE device

Tags: arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi i need to write the following to my BLE device, it actually enable the device to send the data back or notify of the values. However after several attempts and changing the type of the data to be sent which is actually.

```
0xFD-0xFD-0xFA-0x05-0x0D-0x0A
```

i am not able to enable the device. Using the nRF application, i can write these directly which enable the device as well.
i know i need to use the byte array but i am not sure how should i add these to byte array. and when i add them directly to the

```
writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the perfect and workable answer for the question posted. If any one is seeing it then please use the link below
[How do I initialize a byte array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208479/how-do-i-initialize-a-byte-array-in-java)