# use of { } in java while initializing as an array

Tags: java

```
int[] outSize = new int[]{bytes, packets};

new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

What does the first line of code mean? What is it doing to size array?
How is the second line of code initializing that byte array (if it is at all)?

Comment: what do you want to know exactly

Comment: int [ ] outsize = new int[10].. 

i know what that does, but what is { } doing here??

Comment: the code is not correct. and will give compilation error

Comment: well i can compile it with maven ...

Comment: then bytes and packets are integers and they are initialized in outSize array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208479/how-do-i-initialize-a-byte-array-in-java
i can see use of similar pattern here but dont know what it is?

Comment: please update your code currently its unclear what exactly you are not getting in the given code.

Comment: That is simply the syntax to use when creating an array and providing the array entries directly.

Answer (score 0):

We can initialized an array at the time of declaration using the given syntex

```
int[] outSize = new int[]{5, 9}; //create a Integer array of 2 element named outSize
```

OR

```
 int bytes = 5, packets =9;
 int[] outSize = new int[]{bytes, packets}; //create a Integer array of 2 element named outSize.
```

there is no difference using both the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

**First line**

```
int[] outSize = new int{ bytes, packets };
```

This creates an integer (primitive) array with two integer elements, namely `bytes` and `packets`.

**Second line**

```
new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

By itself, this will give you an error (not compile) since it isn't a statement (there's no assignment to a variable anywhere).

If you write

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

you are declaring a byte array called `bytes` with four elements.

**Use of {} for array initialization**

Refer to chapter 10 (arrays) of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html), particularly sections 10.1 and 10.2.

Also worth reading, the [primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

From the above:

`int` is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer (min value in base 10 is `-2^31` and max is `2^31 - 1`).

`byte` is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer (min value in base 10 is `-2^7` and max is `-2^7 - 1`).

**What it's doing**

The first line uses 64 bits to store two integers.

The second line uses 32 bits to store four bytes.