# How to convert hex string to Shift JIS encoding in java?

Tags: java, string, encoding, hex, shift-jis

How can I convert a word's HEX code string to Shift JIS encoding?

For example, I have a string:

"90DD92E882F08F898AFA89BB82B582DC82B782A9"

And I want to get the following output:

設定を初期化しますか

Comment: Use [`HexFormat.of().parseHex(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208685/12567365) followed by [`String s2 = new String(bytes, "Shift_JIS");`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990982/12567365). Assumes you have Java 17+ for the first step.

Comment: @andrewJames – I have not checked it, but assuming that it is correct, you should issue it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = new String(new BigInteger("90DD92E882F08F898AFA89BB82B582DC82B782A9", 16).toByteArray(), "Shift_JIS");
```

will do it for you for earlier versions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Java 17+, which added [`java.util.HexFormat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208685/12567365), then you can use `parseHex` followed by a conversion [from the byte array to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990941/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-java-string/13990982#):

```java
byte[] bytes = HexFormat.of().parseHex("90DD92E882F08F898AFA89BB82B582DC82B782A9");
String str = new String(bytes, "Shift_JIS");
```

If you do not have Java 17+, then the related answer I linked to gives an alternative approach instead of `parseHex`.

I don't have the correct charset/font to show the result in my console, but here is the `str` variable in my debugger:

[image]